# MySQL In Clause performace in case of list have duplicate elements and not sorted

Tags: mysql

if list of value for `IN` clause in mysql have duplicate values and not sorted does it affect performance of query.

for example

```
SELECT * FROM `t1` WHERE `id` IN (2,2,3,1,1);
```

v/s

```
SELECT * FROM `t1` WHERE `id` IN (1,2,3);
```

Answer (score 5):

`MySQL` will get rid of distinct values and sort them on optimizing stage.

This will marginally affect performance, but with most real-world queries you won't notice any difference (it's order of milliseconds).

Comment: I think you meant `duplicate` values instead of `distinct` values. Great insight though as to how MySQL processes queries. Is there any documentation anywhere on these?

Answer (score 0):

You need to worry about this, when you are using some query like:

```
SELECT * FROM `t1` WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `id` FROM `t2`);
```

And the returing number of rows in `t2` is greater that 1000!