# Select Query with IN clause - having duplicate values in IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have a query as below,

```
SELECT count(*) from Employee where e_id IN (121, 234, 536, 234).
```

In above query, `234` is repeated twice.

But the above query returns result with `count = 3` instead of 4.

**My Question is how duplicate data gets filtered in Select query when i have not used `DISTINCT`.**

or **how does database treats IN clause**, is it sort of `List`(duplicate values) or `Set`(unique values) or neither.

Comment: If you wish to know the performance impacts, have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944339/mysql-in-clause-performace-in-case-of-list-have-duplicate-elements-and-not-sorte

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause only filters rows.  It does not multiply them.

So, if a row matches one condition or all conditions doesn't matter.  The row simply is filtered or not filtered.

If you want duplicates, then use a `JOIN`:

```
select count(*)
from employee e join
     (select 121 as e_id union all
      select 234 union all
      select 536 union all
      select 234
     ) matches
     using (e_id);
```

Comment: i hve further updated my q's, how does database treats IN clause, is it sort of List(duplicate values) or Set(unique values) or neither.

Comment: @ankur-singhal What difference does it make? Either a row is in the result of not. If it matches twice, it's in the result.

Comment: @ankur-singhal it is treated as a set. See also my answer.

Answer (score 5):

`e_id IN (121, 234, 536, 234)` works as predicate: for every row of `Employee`, the value of `e_id` is checked to see if it matches with any of the values in list. So `(121, 234, 536, 234)` is treated as a set here.